# MySql query taking long time

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I have the following tables:

```
Table 1 : Contacts
Fields : id  first_name

Values : 

1    Reeta
2    Rohan
3    John 

Table 2 : email (it contains contact_id of contacts table)
Fields : id   contact_id  email_address

Values :

1  1  r@gmail.com
2  2  r@gmail.com
3  3  j@gmail.com
```

I want to display all duplicates by email. Like this:

```
cont_id  first_name  email_address

   1        Reeta  r@gmail.com
   2        Rohan  r@gmail.com
```

Here is my query :

```
select contact_id 
from contacts 
where email_address IN (
  SELECT S.email_address 
  FROM  contacts R
  INNER JOIN email
    ON R.id = S.contact_id 
  Group By email_address
  Having Count(S.id) > 1
);
```

The query takes long time to execute with large number of records. However the inner query works faster but not the outer one. Please Help.

Comment: How long with how many records?

Comment: What indexes have you created? id, contact_id, email_address need indexes

Answer (score 0):

I would move your `INNER JOIN` outside of your subquery.

```
SELECT
    c.contact_id,
    c.first_name,
    e.email_address
FROM contacts c
INNER JOIN email e ON c.id = e.contact_id
WHERE e.email_address IN (
    SELECT email_address
    FROM contacts
    GROUP BY email_address
    HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
);
```

You could also implement MySQL's [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html&ei=nuoMU4rEKaXf0gHK9YD4Bg&usg=AFQjCNGw3-giPVxxfYMV37J3W043nig68g&sig2=qlukIOXdhBI5y0W_DMtOwQ&bvm=bv.61725948,d.dmQ) to get a better idea what's choking your query.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, which should be quicker, is something like this:

```
select email.email_address, group_concat(contacts.contact_id)
from contacts inner join email on contacts.contact_id=email.contact_id
group by email.email_address 
having count(contacts.contact_id) > 1;
```

Now, you're getting exactly what you want; the only thing is, the contact IDs will be concatenated as a comma-separated string. But you'll know which email addresses are non-unique.

You should also have indexes on `contact_id` in all tables (because you join on these fields), and probably `email_address` as well (since you search on it).